# How to add reviews alongside ratings using the Fivestar module?

Tags: rating

I want the user to write a review and rate (field while editing).
I want the other users to write their comments with their rates (field while editing).

I want to see the main rate (field while viewing) as result of user's rates.

The rates submitted on comment go in the main rate, but the author's rate not.

How can I fix this problem? I'm wrong, or is it a limitation of module?

I use Drupal 7.